# Rerender Components when session storage is updated - Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, rerender

So I am currently creating a build-a-burger website in angular. The ingredients and inventory should update depending on the location. The user selects the location from a select menu in the nav.

I am having to hard reload my page every time to get the new locations inventory to load. How can I make it rerender immediately when the location is updated in session storage?

This is my app.component.html:

```
  <select id="locations" appAuthOnly [isVerified]="isVerified" [(ngModel)]="selectedLocation"  (change)="onLocationChange()">
<option value="Mystic Falls">Mystic Falls</option>
<option value="Riverdale">Riverdale</option>
<option value="Sunnydale">Sunnydale</option>
```

This is the app.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.isVerified = localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false;
console.log(this.selectedLocation);
this.selectedLocation = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedLocation') || 'Mystic Falls';
  }

  onLocationChange() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedLocation', this.selectedLocation);
  }
```

UPDATED:

```
onLocationChange() {
  sessionStorage.setItem('selectedLocation', this.selectedLocation);
  this.ingrediantService.getAllItems();
}
}
```

My ingrediants.service.ts:

```
  selectedLocation: string = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedLocation') ?? '';

  getAllItems(): Observable<Ingrediant[]> {
    const selectedLocation = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedLocation') ?? '';
    return this.http.get<Ingrediant[]>(this.url).pipe(
      map(ingredients => ingredients.filter(ingredient => ingredient.location === selectedLocation))     
    );

  }
```

And lastly - inventory-ingrediants.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Retrieve the ingredients
    this.ingrediantService.getAllItems().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.breadIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Bread');
        this.pattyIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Patty');
        this.cheeseIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Cheese');
        this.garnishIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Garnish');
        this.sauceIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Sauce');
    });

    this.carousel = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.carousel-container');
    this.arrowLeft = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.arrow-left');
    this.arrowRight = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.arrow-right');

    // Subscribe to the watchSessionStorage method to listen for changes to the session storage
 
        
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Observables is reactive to changes, but you need to declare at your storage the kind of changes will be made, and need to be aware who will trigger the changes.

When you have 1-or-many components listening to changes, and some other events responsible to changes, in this example, i believe the best aproach is to use [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject#behaviorsubject) (that extends and observable), you need to store the shared observable in the `ingrediants.service`, like so:

ingrediants.service.ts:

```
items$: new BehaviorSubject<Ingrediant[]>([]);

 getAllItems(): void {
     const selectedLocation = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedLocation') ?? '';

    this.http.get<Ingrediant[]>(this.url).pipe(
        map(ingredients => ingredients.filter(
            ingredient => ingredient.location === selectedLocation
        )
    )).subscribe((res) => this.items$.next(res));
}
```

And in all other places in your code, you just need to refer to items$, like so:

some-file.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)">{{item.name}}</div>
```

or in some-file.ts:

```
method() {
    this.ingrediantService.items$.subscribe((items) => {
        console.log(items);
    });
}
```

So on your app.component.ts, on app start, you need to make the first call to ingredients, like so:

app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //... your code here

    this.ingrediantService.getAllItems();
}
```

And whenever you need to update the items data, just call:

```
this.ingrediantService.getAllItems();
```

And will automatically update all subscribers

Comment: whenever you want to update the items$ list, you have to call `getAllItems()`. Check the implementation of this method above, the important part is when it call `this.items$.next(res)`, that the part that will trigger an event to Subject and update all listeners

Comment: So I have implemented it that way - I only adjusted how items$ was defined by making it like so:
  items$: BehaviorSubject<Ingrediant[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Ingrediant[]>([]);

I have all called the getAllItems(); on the locationChange() function but I am still receiving an empty array

Would it be helpful if I updated my previous question code to show what I have?

Comment: So when I add getAllItems() to the ingrediant page it works - but the items need to rerender when the selected location changes - and this is done through clicking on aa select option present in the app.component - the ingredients is in a different component so it needs to detect the change made on a separate component

Comment: @AlexaPettitt, It is necessary to call getAllItems on app startup. I will update my answare

Comment: Yes I am aware - and I have done that. My problem is that I do not want to need to reload the page to see the new inventory when I change the location. I want the components to rerender immediately when the location is changed and that is not happening. It is still requiring me to reload the page.

Comment: Do you insert `getAllItems()` in the final of the method `onLocationChange`?

Comment: Yes - I have updated my question code above to show the new onLocationChange()

Comment: @AlexaPettitt can you generate an StackBlitz? So i can check.

Answer (score 0):

When you select is change I cant see the new call for the update, pleae see the code below, of course you can manipulate as you want `onLocationChange()` function.
My sugestion is each time that select input change do a new request

```
ngOnInit() {

    // FIRST CALL
    this.getIngredients()

    this.carousel = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.carousel-container');
    this.arrowLeft = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.arrow-left');
    this.arrowRight = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.arrow-right');


}
   
getIngredients() {
   this.ingrediantService.getAllItems().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.breadIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Bread');
        this.pattyIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Patty');
        this.cheeseIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Cheese');
        this.garnishIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Garnish');
        this.sauceIngrediants = data.filter(ingredient => ingredient.category === 'Sauce');
    });
}

onLocationChange() {
     sessionStorage.setItem('selectedLocation', this.selectedLocation);
     // EACH TIME SELECT CHANGE NEW CALL IS EXECUTED
     this.getIngredients();

}
```

Comment: But onLocationChange is in a separate component - so how would I go about that?

Comment: In you code app.component.ts and app.component.html are the component, html and ts are linked

Comment: So the code you provided must go into the app.component.ts?

Comment: yes, my code is in app.component.ts

Comment: But then how do I get this functionality to execute in the inventory-ingrediants component? Do I delete what I had previously? I use app.vodule.routing to navigate between pages, i don't call them in the app.component.html

Comment: depend of how the component inventory-ingredients is in your view, you can send the update with @input or you can make a service with behavior subject

Comment: add you code in stackbiz and share here, I can help better